# How can we show that $\mu_t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\delta_0$ iff $\mu_t\left(B_\varepsilon(0)\right)\xrightarrow{t\to0+}1$ for all $\varepsilon>0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $\delta_0$ denote the Dirac measure concentrated at $0\in E$ and $\mu_t$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal B(E)$.

> How can we show that

1. $\mu_t\xrightarrow{t\to\infty+}\delta_0$ weakly;
2. $\mu_t\left(B_\varepsilon(0)\right)\xrightarrow{t\to\infty+}1$ for all $\varepsilon>0$

are equivalent?

By definition, (1.) is equivalent to $$\int f\:{\rm d}\mu_t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\tag1$$ for all bounded and continuous $f:E\to\mathbb R$. On the other hand, by the Portmanteau theorem, (1.) is equivalent $$\liminf_{t\ge0}\mu_t(C)=\mu(C)\;\;\;\text{for all open }C\subseteq E\tag2.$$

The proof of the latter is essentially a consequence of the following result: If $\emptyset\subset A\subseteq E$ and $C\subset E$ with $\overline A\subseteq C^\circ$, then there is a bounded and continuous $f:E\to\mathbb R$ with $=\le f\le 1$ and \begin{align}\left.f\right|_A&=1;\tag3\\\left.f\right|_{E\setminus C}&=0.\tag4\end{align}

Mimicking the proof build up on this result, we could conclude from (1.) that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a bounded and continuous $f_\varepsilon:E\to\mathbb R$ with $0\le f_\varepsilon\le1$ and \begin{align}\left.f\right|_{B_\varepsilon(0)}&=1;\tag5\\\left.f\right|_{E\setminus B_{2\varepsilon}(0)}&=0.\tag6\end{align} Now, $$\mu_t\left(B_\varepsilon(0)\right)+\int_{B_{2\varepsilon}(0)\setminus B_\varepsilon(0)}f_\varepsilon\:{\rm d}\mu_t=\int f_\varepsilon\:{\rm d}\mu_t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}1\tag7$$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. However, this will not yield (2.) and nothing which wouldn't already be clear from $(2)$ ...

> So, how do we need to argue and how can we show the other direction?

Comment: It is a simple application of the Portmanteau, (see pages 2-9 of this [link](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/weak.pdf)) , in articular the bit that states that $\mu_n\Longrightarrow\mu$ iff $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu_n(A)=\mu(A)$ for any measurable set $A$ fir which $\mu(\partial A)=0$. In you case, $\delta_0(\partial B(0;\varepsilon))=0$ and thus, everything is kosher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume we have that $(E, \|\cdot\|)$ is separable, so we de not need too sophisticated versions of the portmanteau theorem.

> Thm (Portmanteau) tfae:
>
> 1. $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly;
> 2. $\liminf_n \mu_n U \geq \mu U$ for all open $U\subset E$;
> 3. Various other interesting formulations which we shall not need here...

Assume $\mu_n\to \delta_0$. Then (by $1\implies 2$ with $U=B_\epsilon$) $1\geq \limsup \mu_n B_\epsilon \geq \liminf \mu_n B_\epsilon \geq \delta_0 B_\epsilon =1$, which shows that there exists $\lim_n \mu_n B_\epsilon=1$.

Viceversa, assume $\lim_n \mu_n B_\epsilon=1$ and let $U$ be open. If $0\notin U$, then $\liminf_n \mu_n U \geq \delta_0 U= 0$. If $0\in U$, then $B_\epsilon \subset U$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, and therefore $\liminf_n \mu_n U \geq \liminf_n \mu_n B_\epsilon = \lim_n B_\epsilon =1 \geq \delta_0 B_\epsilon$. Since $U$ was arbitrary, the conclusion follows from $2\implies 1$.